# Jquery UI draggable not working in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='.../wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&amp;load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload&amp;ver=4.6.1'></script>//jQuery v1.12.4
<script type='text/javascript' src='.../jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js?ver=1.0.0'></script>// My jquery UI files version v1.12.1
<script type='text/javascript' src='.../my-main.js'></script>
```

Scripts in my-main.js

```
(function( $ ) {
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nt_draggale").draggable();
});

})( jQuery );
```

But it's not working. In console, it's say:

```
jquery-ui.min.js?ver=1.0.0:6 Uncaught TypeError: this._addClass is not a function(…)
```

Comment: you can check view page source, path of library file is correct or not.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error, the solution is here : http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/using-jqueryui-in-wordpress/

In your case :

```
wp_enqueue_script("jquery-ui-draggable");
```

(Works perfectly for me with Wordpress 4.6.1).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code, it's working fine for me so please provide more detail.

**Note**

for wordpress backend no need to add jQuery it's already included